# Struggling to get month name by using mysql join query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get month name from the below query :

```
SELECT 
   a.`user_name`, 
   MONTH(b.`registered_month`) 
FROM 
  `users` as a, 
  `registered_details` as b 
WHERE 
  a.`user_id`=b.`user_id`
```

But It returns `NULL` value in `MONTH(b.registered_month)` field.

Comment: What is `b.\`registered_month\`` when `MONTH(b.\`registered_month\`)` is null?

Comment: what format is registered_month ?

Comment: post the sample date from your registered_month column

Comment: And, why are you using the weird quotes `user_id` etc ? Wouldn't just a.user_id work ? Is this a MySql thing ?

Comment: @okaram, yes the quotes are a mysql thing, but you're right it would work without them as well, in this case.

Comment: @WizKid : b.`registered_month` having `1,2,3..` month numbers, I want to get month name so, I am using `MONTH(e.registered_month)`.

Comment: @Tanatos : `registered_month` format is `varchar(255)`

Comment: MONTH takes a date and return the month. So `SELECT MONTH('2008-02-03');` returns 2.

Comment: @WizKid : Then how to get monthname ?

Comment: SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m'));//returns January

Comment: @fortune: When I used `SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(e.registered_month, '%m'));` It returns the `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'` error.

Comment: Syntax is correct and it should work. See Example @ [*MySQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/38425)

Answer (score 2):

The `month` function will only work on date fields.  It returns the numeric month of the given date (i.e. 1 for 2014-01-01).  There is also a function called `monthname` that gives you the name of the month of the given date.

One other note about your query. Typically, your join should use `on` instead of where to join the tables.

```
 `users` as a JOIN 
 `registered_details` as b 
ON 
  a.`user_id`=b.`user_id`
```

**EDIT**
Since registered_month is a numeric value (1,2,3 etc), you'll need to use a case statement

```
SELECT
  CASE b.registered_month
  WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
  END CASE as theMonth
```

Comment: ... not only the `ON` clause, but also replace the old-school comma join syntax with the `JOIN` keyword.

Comment: Good catch. Meant to change that as well.

Answer (score 2):

If your current setting of sql_mode allows for "zero" dates, and if `b.registered_month` returns a string (or integer that can be converted to string) as a valid value for numeric month (e.g. 1, 2, 3, ..., 12)

You can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert that value into a MySQL `DATE`, and then use the `DATE_FORMAT` function to extract the month name from the `DATE`.

e.g.

```
SELECT a.user_name
     , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(b.registered_month,'%m'),'%M') AS registered_month_name
  FROM users a
  JOIN registered_details b 
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
 ORDER BY a.user_name
```

If your sql_mode does not allow for zero dates, you'll need to provide a valid year and month. You could use CONCAT to string together a valid string representation of a date, using your month value, using (e.g.) an expression like this:

```
CONCAT('2014-',b.registered_month,'-01')
```

in place of `b.registered_month` (as the first argument in the STR_TO_DATE function in the query above, and make a corresponding change to the second argument e.g. `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

You could also use an expression like this, to generate a valid DATE (avoiding the STR_TO_DATE function)

```
DATE_FORMAT('2014-01-01' + INTERVAL ( b.registered_month - 1) MONTH, '%M') AS rm_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(e.registered_month, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Make sure the format in STR_TO_DATE is the one you have in registered_month

Comment: As the comments on the question say months is a single int between 1 and 12.

Comment: You can do something similar with a concatenation